# How to compile package with sub-directory includes in SCons?

Tags: makefile, scons, xmp

`scons` output (split for readability), [relevant commit](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc/tree/752e41f1346cf3a55a9f0e1da29afabcea67afb9):

```
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/XMP/XMPCore/source/ExpatAdapter.o -c -O2 -iquote- -DUNIX_ENV=1 \
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Ifixes/XMP-Toolkit -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/build \
-IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/source/common -IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/XMPCore/source \
-IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/source/XMPFiles \
-IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/source/XMPFiles/FileHandlers \
-IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/source/XMPFiles/FormatSupport \
-IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/third-party/MD5 \
-IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/public/include \
XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/XMPCore/source/ExpatAdapter.cpp
XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/XMPCore/source/ExpatAdapter.cpp:9:77: fatal error:
public/include/XMP_Environment.h: No such file or directory
 #include "public/include/XMP_Environment.h" // ! Must be the first #include!
                                                                             ^
```

It seems XMP started using relative includes in files rather than relying on compiler options. How do I handle this new include style in SCons?

(Background: When trying to compile [dcp2icc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcp2icc/) (using a [`Makefile`](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc/blob/1b545b3ce776266ed29096ba712de32188484973/Makefile) based on the original `ReadMe.txt`) I got a bunch of errors like `'strlen' is not a member of 'std'`, which seems to be because of an [include clean-up in GCC](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2011653.html). Rather than patch a bunch of third party libraries I decided to try a newer version of XMP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to solve this include fail pretty much the same as you would on the command-line: by adding the missing include path, which in your case seems to be "-IXMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306". So, add your origXMP to the CPPPATH as well...